# Email contact on iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, email

I know we can retrieve email contacts from the "Contacts" app.

What if I want to retrieve other email from let's say gmail inside my app. Is this possible?

Is there an sdk to retrieve it? e.g (the app will prompt user to login to gmail, and it will send back all the email contact)

What about Yahoo and Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112898/gmail-api-with-ios-getting-emails) about Gmail might help you.

I think similar to Gmail case, you can do with [Exchange API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations) and [Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/mail/)

But Yahoo currently says:

> Access to Yahoo’s IMAP service is one of the top requests from the application developer community. We are happy to announce that a Yahoo IMAP service with OAuth-2.0 will be available in early 2015. As announced on Dec 19th, 2014, we will no longer support the current Yahoo-customized Mail APIs after February 16, 2015. We will provide a migration path to this new service, which will allow us to better serve the developer community. For more information, send a mail to imap-service@yahoo-inc.com.

Comment: Thanks @keyv. I'm unfamiliar with these api, but at least now I am on the right track. Will explore it. :D

Comment: hey keyv, what I want is to get the email contact instead of the email. Is there a way to do it? There's a typo in my question

Comment: @user1872384 i think you should dig 
[here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts)